# Run-time error 1004 when closing workbook that has no macros

Tags: excel

Details will be a little sparse as I'm trying to answer a coworker's question to me. They have been working with me to create a macro to automate condensing some data and applying it to a pre-formatted template sheet for use in a report.

While doing some clean-up actions I suggested (removing screen scrolls & such that got captured when they recorded some steps) they started having Excel throw a 1004 when closing files.

The issue apparently occurs both when the macro-enabled workbook I'm helping with is open, AND when they have no workbooks with macros open.

What's more frustrating is the Debug button is disabled in the error window. So there's nothing to really provided any idea where the error is originating.

Has anyone seen anything similar to provide ideas on how to even troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is something trying to reference a worksheet that no longer exists? Without seeing the vba itself it'll be very hard to tell.

Comment: Does their `Personal.xlsb` file maybe have macros that could be triggering it?  Does this occur in new files they open and close?

Comment: J. Fox, there are no macros/vba in the workbook being closed, that's the whole reason this is even posted. Even if there were, the debug button wasn't click-able so I'd have no idea what particular piece of VBA to implicate. BruceWayne I don't even monkey with `Personal.xlsb` so I'm doubtful that the person I'm helping has. Thus far the issue has only occurred at close.

Comment: There must be some VBA running in order for the error to pop like that. On their machine, when all other macro-enabled books are closed, snoop around their VBE (Alt+F11) and insure there are no other VBAProjects loaded (perhaps an .xla that wouldn't be associated to a workbook). Since the debug button is grayed out, it suggests that the relevant VBAProject is also password protected. Removing it from excel Developer>>Add-Ins will get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. I'll look into those

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by disabling the Analysis ToolPak - VBA Add-in.